# Bootstrap Grid with HTML5 Sections and Aside

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am using the ***Bootstrap 4 grid system***, and want to float an aside down the right hand side of the screen.

Currently my **MAIN** content is wrapped in **col-xl-3**, I want the **ASIDE** to also use **col-xl-3**, but I want it to run the height of the page, not just the height of the row it is in, as it is currently pushing the height of the row out...

As you can see from the image, my aside is pushing the top row higher than the bottom...

[image]

All I have done code wise is this;

```
section.body article, section.body aside { float: left; clear: both; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used "col-sm" but the principle is still the same. It's all about the nesting.

View in full page to see columns.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" role="main">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">2</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">3</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">4</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">5</div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">6</div>
              </div>
          </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="row">Nav</div>
          <div class="row">Nav</div>
          <div class="row">Nav</div>
          <div class="row">Nav</div>
          <div class="row">Nav</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are correct mate, I thought there might be some clever way to do this, as BootStraps Grid system is pretty clever, but I just need to plan my layout's better :/